# /siprtp: symbol lookup error: ./siprtp: undefined symbol: pj_ansi_strxcpy

Tags: c, ubuntu, arm, pjsip

In pjsip there is a class called siprtp.c at the following address:

> ~/pjsip/pjproject-2.13/pjsip-apps/src/samples

This class contains a reference to the siprtp_report.c class at the same address. The pj_ansi_strxcpy method is used inside the siprtp_report.c class. I use the below Makefile to compile siprtp.c and it compiles successfully:

```
PJDIR = ~/pjsip/pjproject-2.13
include $(PJDIR)/build.mak

siprtp: siprtp.o 
        $(PJ_CC) -o $@ $< $(PJ_LDFLAGS) $(PJ_LDLIBS)

siprtp.o: siprtp.c
        $(PJ_CC) -c -o $@ $< $(PJ_CFLAGS)

clean:
        rm -f siprtp.o siprtp
```

output:

```
(base) parsaeeyan@KT12:~/pjsip/pjproject-2.13/pjsip-apps/src/samples$ make
arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -c -o siprtp.o siprtp.c -DPJ_AUTOCONF=1 -O2 -DPJ_IS_BIG_ENDIAN=0 -DPJ_IS_LITTLE_ENDIAN=1 -fPIC         -I/home/parsaeeyan/pjsip/pjproject-2.13/pjlib/include -I/home/parsaeeyan/pjsip/pjproject-2.13/pjlib-util/include -I/home/parsaeeyan/pjsip/pjproject-2.13/pjnath/include -I/home/parsaeeyan/pjsip/pjproject-2.13/pjmedia/include -I/home/parsaeeyan/pjsip/pjproject-2.13/pjsip/include
In file included from /home/parsaeeyan/pjsip/pjproject-2.13/pjlib/include/pj/except.h:29,
                 from /home/parsaeeyan/pjsip/pjproject-2.13/pjlib/include/pjlib.h:34,
                 from siprtp.c:75:
siprtp.c: In function ‘logger_on_tx_msg’:
siprtp.c:1978:26: warning: format ‘%ld’ expects argument of type ‘long int’, but argument 3 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat=]
 1978 |     PJ_LOG(4,(THIS_FILE, "TX %ld bytes %s to %s:%d:\n"
      |                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
......
 1981 |                          (tdata->buf.cur - tdata->buf.start),
      |                          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                                          |
      |                                          int
siprtp.c:1978:32: note: format string is defined here
 1978 |     PJ_LOG(4,(THIS_FILE, "TX %ld bytes %s to %s:%d:\n"
      |                              ~~^
      |                                |
      |                                long int
      |                              %d
arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -o siprtp siprtp.o -L/home/parsaeeyan/pjsip/pjproject-2.13/pjlib/lib -L/home/parsaeeyan/pjsip/pjproject-2.13/pjlib-util/lib -L/home/parsaeeyan/pjsip/pjproject-2.13/pjnath/lib -L/home/parsaeeyan/pjsip/pjproject-2.13/pjmedia/lib -L/home/parsaeeyan/pjsip/pjproject-2.13/pjsip/lib -L/home/parsaeeyan/pjsip/pjproject-2.13/third_party/lib        -lpjsua -lpjsip-ua -lpjsip-simple -lpjsip -lpjmedia-codec -lpjmedia-videodev -lpjmedia-audiodev -lpjmedia -lpjnath -lpjlib-util  -lsrtp -lresample -lgsmcodec -lspeex -lilbccodec -lg7221codec  -lpj -lm -lrt -lpthread  -lasound
```

But at runtime it gives me this error: "./siprtp: symbol lookup error: ./siprtp: undefined symbol: pj_ansi_strxcpy"

The pj_ansi_strxcpy method is defined in this path: ~/pjsip/pjproject-2.13/pjlib/src/pj/string.c. How to add this class to siprtp.c?